# Oracle select query give priority to column value

Tags: sql, oracle, select

I have three columns in one table Test

```
name, type, region
```

Sample values are:

```
john IT ny
john SALES ny
john FINANCE ny
lisa SALES ny
lisa FINANCE ny
```

Out of the above condition how can i  give priority 1 to IT, 2 to SALES and 3 to Finance.

I mean for the above sample records it shuld give 2 records

```
John IT ny
Lisa SALES ny
```

If employee records are with IT than only those should show, if not than show SALES, if not than show Finance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest adding a table to store `TYPES` and their associated priorities - if you add a `FOREIGN KEY` constraint between your table and the table of types then you can assert that the type always has a priority.

An alternate way of getting the priorities would be to create a function which takes a type as an input and returns a priority. It would give similar functionality as a table but is slightly more obfuscated.

Other than that - I agree with @Ben that analytical functions are the best way to get the results out.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ce62b/1)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE types (
  type VARCHAR2(20) PRIMARY KEY,
  priority NUMBER(3)
)
/

INSERT INTO types
          SELECT 'IT',        1 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'SALES',     2 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'FINANCE',   3 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'MARKETING', NULL FROM DUAL
/

CREATE TABLE minions (
  name   VARCHAR2(30),
  type   VARCHAR2(20),
  region VARCHAR2(2),
  FOREIGN KEY ( type ) REFERENCES types ( type )
)
/

INSERT INTO minions
          SELECT 'john',  'IT',        'ny' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'john',  'SALES',     'ny' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'john',  'FINANCE',   'ny' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'john',  'MARKETING', 'ny' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'kevin', 'MARKETING', 'ny' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'lisa',  'SALES',     'ny' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'lisa',  'FINANCE',   'ny' FROM DUAL
/
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT name,
       MAX( m.type ) KEEP ( DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY priority ) AS type,
       MAX( region ) KEEP ( DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY priority ) AS region
FROM   minions m
       INNER JOIN
       types t
       ON ( m.type = t.type )
WHERE  priority IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY name
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ce62b/1/0)**:

```
| NAME |  TYPE | REGION |
|------|-------|--------|
| john |    IT |     ny |
| lisa | SALES |     ny |
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to choose one, it seems as though a CASE statement would be best:

```
select name
     , max(type) keep (dense_rank first order by priority asc) as type
     , max(region) keep (dense_rank first order by priority asc) as region
  from ( select a.*
              , case type 
                     when 'IT' then 1
                     when 'SALES' then 2
                     when 'FINANCE' then 3
                end as priority 
           from my_table a
                )
 group by name
```

The [`FIRST`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions056.htm) function picks the first ranked value based upon the specified order.

Comment: Thanks for ur query. It worked. Btw what about if there is another row john  MARKETING ny I wont to ignore the records except IT, SALES and finance

Comment: You add `where type <> 'marketing`, or, `where type in ('it','sales','finance')`