# select query with priority based on column values

Tags: sql, oracle11g

This is a continuation of the question asked in : [select query with priority based on column values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20284023/oracle-select-query-give-priority-to-column-value)
I have an identical issue wherein my result set (which is a flight movement report of an airport) is like this :

```
sl_no term   arr  org   sta   ata  arr_pax  asrc   dep   dep_pax  dsrc  std    atd   
----- ----  ---  ----  ---  -----  -----   ----- -----  ---- -  -----   ----   --- 
01    D    TY123 TTY  00:00  00:05  123    USR  II 877    26     LDM   00:45  00:50
02    D    TY123 TTY  00:00  00:05   55    LDM  II 877    26     LDM   00:45  00:50
03    D    FY598 TTY  00:00  00:05  123    LDM  II 877    32     USR   00:45  00:50
04    D    ZX555 TTY  00:00  00:05  223    LDM  II 877    55     LDM   00:45  00:50
05    D    XX645 TTY  00:00  00:05   16    LDM  II 877    55     LDM   00:45  00:50
06    D    XX645 TTY  00:00  00:05  16     LDM  II 877    65     USR   00:45  00:50
```

Now, you can observe that, the first two rows are identical but for the values under the column 'asrc' ('USR' and 'LDM'). Similarly, rows 5 and 6 are identical except for the values ('USR' and 'LDM') under the column 'dsrc'.

My target result should contain only one of the identical rows in the order that, if 'USR' is present, the row containing 'LDM' will be discarded. If 'USR' is absent and 'LDM' is the only one present, then the row will be selected.

The second answer in the linked question suggested the use of analytical functions. I tried to do that and I ended up with the below query :

An excerpt :

```
SELECT term,arr,org,sta,ata,arr_pax,asrc,dep,dep_pax,dsrc,std,atd,Max(dep_pax) KEEP (Dense_Rank first ORDER BY apriority) FROM
(
Select .....<joins to build the query>
, CASE dpriority
  WHEN 'USR' THEN 1
  WHEN 'LDM' THEN 2
END AS dpriority
, CASE dpriority
  WHEN 'USR' THEN 1
  WHEN 'LDM' THEN 2
END AS dpriority FROM
...... ;
```

I still end up with the same result set with the both rows with 'USR' and 'LDM' values. Can anyone point out how to construct the analytical function here?

Any other working approaches are also welcome.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe HAVING clause is what you're missing here:
http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.1.2/ref/rrefsqlj14854.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following logic should do this:

```
SELECT term, arr, org, sta, ata, arr_pax, asrc, dep, dep_pax, dsrc, std, atd,
       Max(dep_pax) KEEP (Dense_Rank first ORDER BY apriority)
FROM (select t.*,
             sum(case when dpriority = 'USR' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by . . . ) as NumUSR,
             sum(case when dpriority = 'LDM' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by . . . ) as NumLDM
      from t
     ) t
WHERE dpriority = 'USR' or NumUSR = 0;
```

It counts the number of "USR" values and the number of "LDM" values (strictly speaking, the latter is not necessary).  The logic is to take the "USR" value if available or any value if there are no USR values.

I'm not sure what the right partitioning key is.  You can put in all the columns, although a smaller subset might be sufficient.

Comment: It worked. Thanks. To others who are facing the same issue, the snippet "Max(dep_pax) KEEP (Dense_Rank first ORDER BY apriority)" in the answer provided by Gordon is not relevant. Just thought to add this in case anybody's thrown offtrack by that...